# Json RestSharp deserilizing Response Data null

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

i use RestSharp to access a Rest API. I like to get Data back as an POCO.
My RestSharp Client looks like this:

```
var client = new RestClient(@"http:\\localhost:8080");
        var request = new RestRequest("todos/{id}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", "4");
        //request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
        //With enabling the next line I get an new empty object of TODO
        //as Data
        //client.AddHandler("*", new JsonDeserializer());
        IRestResponse<ToDo> response2 = client.Execute<ToDo>(request);
        ToDo td=new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<ToDo>(response2);

        var name = response2.Data.name;
```

my Class for the JsonObject looks like this:

```
public class ToDo
{
    public int id;
    public string created_at;
    public string updated_at;
    public string name;
}
```

and the Json Response:

```
{
    "id":4,
    "created_at":"2015-06-18 09:43:15",
    "updated_at":"2015-06-18 09:43:15",
    "name":"Another Random Test"
}
```

Comment: I passed by this. In my case, I have create a new constructor with parameters, and I forgot it create a constructor without parameter.

Answer (score 18):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization), RestSharp only deserializes to properties and you're using fields.

> RestSharp uses your class as the starting point, looping through each
>   publicly-accessible, writable property and searching for a
>   corresponding element in the data returned.

You need to change your `ToDo` class to the following:

```
public class ToDo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I changed the class and now this works:
client.AddHandler("*", new JsonDeserializer());
IRestResponse<ToDo> response2 = client.Execute<ToDo>(request);
ToDo td = response2.Data;

Comment: @ThomasKaemmerling Glad to hear it!  If my answer helped you, accepting it would be greatly appreciated.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow